# Meteor multiple event handlers attached when showing and hiding templates

Tags: events, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm having an issue with nested templates in Meteor.

If I have a template like this, with a child template inside it:

In parentTemplate.js

```
{{#if showParentTemplate}}
    {{> parentTemplate}}
{{/if}}

<template name="parentTemplate">
    {{> childTemplate}}
</template>
```

In childTemplate.js:

```
<template name="childTemplate">
     <a class="someItem" href="#"></a>
</template>
```

When I register a click event on the element(anchor in this example), then show/hide the parent template on the DOM, I end up with an extra event listener on the anchor for each time I show the parent back on the DOM. I checked the Template.parentTemplate.onDestroy() and it is firing. That should mean the template and its events are being destroyed. I would imaging that includes destroying the child template and its events as well.

Here is a simple handler for the click event

```
Template.childTemplate.events({
    'click .someItem' :(e,template)=>{
        console.log('got it');
    }
})
```

And to clarify, I am attaching the event listeners in the onCreated method, not the onRendered method.

I'm seeing that each time the parentTemplate is shown, the childTemplate fires the onCreated event, then multiple onRendered events. A new onRendered is added with each hide/show of the parentTemplate.

Is there something basic I'm missing here. It seems almost like there are multiple instances of the template on the DOM or the events are never destroyed. is there a correct way to destroy a Meteor template when it is hidden or removed form the DOM?

Comment: I am not sure but is it allowed to write `template` tags within `template` tags? I thought you can include a child template using `{{> child_template_name}}` only.

Comment: Oops! I have a typo in my example. I'll update it to accurately represent the scenario. I accidentally put my `#if` condition around the outside of the `<template>`. Just in the example though. I'll fix it here. Good catch.